# Fill a jquery datatable after a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a 2D myArray[?][9] that I fill on page load, so I can't just write :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            table = $('#example').DataTable({
                data: myArray,
                columns: [
                    { title: "colum 1" },
                    { title: "colum 2" },
                    { title: "colum 3" },
                    { title: "colum 4" },
                    { title: "colum 5" },
                    { title: "colum 6" },
                    { title: "colum 7" },
                    { title: "colum 8 " },
                    { title: "colum 9" }
                ]

            });
        });
```

If I do so, the datatable is empty. So I wanted to fill it after a button click, however I can't put this code in a function or I get a "TypeError: $(…).DataTable is not a function". How should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Alexandre,
Are you including the DataTable assets?
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css

That error just indicates that DataTable is not available to use, likely because assets are not included.

Comment: Hi, I'm including those otherwise it would'nt display anything when I put the above code in my JS. If I do so, I have an empty datatable because my array isn't filled yet, so I wanted to put the code in a function I can call when I want, however it seems that the includes are not recognized inside of a function.

Comment: Can you send the rest of the code? that error indicates the library isn't loaded yet so perhaps you are adding the event prior to loading.

Comment: I found why it wasn't working, I don't know why but when I'm calling my navigation bar file, it makes my datatable fail. I opened a [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43886278/calling-a-navbar-file-makes-my-jquery-datatable-to-fail) about it .