# Calling a navbar file makes my jquery datatable to fail

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a standard navbar file that I took from bootstrap whith this assets :

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

In an other file, I have those :

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAHc6798OWr7qKWWzN8CQWRNTw1IysIw_U&libraries=geometry"> </script>
<script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"> </script>
```

Here is some jquery to call the navbar file :

```
  $.get("navigation.html", function (data) {
    $("#nav-placeholder").replaceWith(data);
});
```

And the body code :

```
    <div id="nav-placeholder">
    </div>
```

If I let the nav-placeholder div in the code, my datatable is failing with the error "TypeError $(...).DataTable is not a function". To get datatables working I need to comment the 2 lines above. Could you explain me why ? I don't think I'm including a link twice. What should I do to keep my navbar ?

P.S : If I put the 2 assets of the navbar file directly into the other, datatables are working well. Is the jquery call the problem here ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should not use replaceWith() but append(). It all depends on what navigation.html is returning.

```
$.get("navigation.html", function (data) {
  $("#nav-placeholder").append(data);
});
```